# How to make a "TreeView"?

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

How to make using `DevExpress`:
  1. `TreeView` based on the database?
  2. `TreeView` was synchronized with the database?
      Changed the contents of the line -> the database was updated.

```
  Dragged the subordinate line to another node -> the database was updated.
```

3. In order to drag-and-drop the `TreeView` elements between nodes.

How to solve all the problems with the help of "designer" or programming.

On the "1" question, I realized that we need to create a `TreeList`, and then set the `TreeList.ViewStyle` property to `TreeView`.
So it is written in the documentation

I created the [`TreeList`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twxQD.jpg).

Where can I change the property `TreeList.ViewStyle`?
How to make a [`TreeView`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o78vZ.jpg)?

Project - [link](http://dropmefiles.com/YIDeu)

Comment: for winforms ? and why dev-express ?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: Code, Code ,Code Show us your Code plz.

Comment: @zackraiyan `for winforms ?` - yes. `and why dev-express ?`- I do not know ... While I choose ...
I would be grateful if you put other options

Comment: @climivin , you sure you want to stick to winforms(very bad choice now a days) ? or do you wish to move to wpf ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I'm just starting to learn programming.
I decided to start with "winforms"
My tasks related to "TreeView" are easier to solve in "wpf"?

Comment: Wpf is like your own body, it let's you do anything and everything @climivin

Comment: @zack raiyan I'll try

Comment: So, should I try to help you with winform or wpf ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I do not want to take your time.
I will try to solve the problems published in this issue in "wpf" on my own. If there are difficulties, can I contact you directly?
Or do I need to post a question on the forum?

Comment: @Hubii project added

Comment: @climivin , of course you can contact me :) [link](https://join.skype.com/NM8xmK9a80KX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [How to make the TreeList control look like a TreeView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1153.aspx) example which illustrates how to achieve your goal.

> Check the TreeList's [TreeView Style](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/119635/Controls-and-Libraries/Tree-List/Feature-Center/Data-Presentation/TreeView-Style) documentation  and you can
>   change the view by setting [TreeList.ViewStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList.ViewStyle.property) Property

Example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            treeList1.ForceInitialize();

            treeList1.Appearance.FocusedCell.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            treeList1.Appearance.FocusedCell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
            treeList1.OptionsBehavior.Editable = false;

            treeList1.ViewStyle = DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeListViewStyle.TreeView;
        }
```